# Routing data for GraphHopper

Tags: android, dictionary, openstreetmap, graphhopper, mapsforge

How to create geometry, edges, location_index, nodes, names and properties file using graphhopper in android programmatically?

I downloaded PocketMaps for reference but can not find out the solution.

I follow the steps from the link https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/android/index.md but doesn't work.

Please, help me out.

Comment: "doesn't work?" What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: You should be more descriptive what you mean with 'doesn't work' as scai pointed out. Programmatically can be done only on the desktop currently with just `graphhopper.importOrLoad();`

Comment: read the map section https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/android/index.md#maps also you need cygwin if you are on windows. Best of luck